# certificate error while posting to user wall with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I m using the PHP facebook sdk v3.0.0 to post comments on Facebook user's wall.
Here is the code used:

```
    $args = array(
        "message" => $message,
        "link" => $link,
        "Caption" => $messageCaption,
    );
    try {
        $postId = $this->api("/$userFBId/feed", "post", $args);
        return $postId;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
```

When I execute it, I got the following error message:

> ## error setting certificate verify locations:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none

I would like to mention that I've added an SSL certificate to my website. It seems that Facebook SDK is using the default location for certificates. But I'm on a shared server and the certificate file is located in a customized folder.

Please, how to solve this issue ? Is there a way to specify to facebook SDK how to use a customized file for CAfile and CApath ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling on this for a while, I thought I should answer to help others solve this issue like I was able to:
Save fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt in the same path as base_facebook.php
Also download fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt directly from sdk location at developers.facebook.com and not any other site including github.